# UITableviewController - Update specific Cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have created custom cells with a button that changes the state of a row from "availible" to "bought", and I also have an UIImageview which shows the state. I want the cell to redraw with the new state when the user presses the button.

I have been able to get the UIImage to be redrawn after the User scrolls the cell out of view. This is what I have so far:

Initialization

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
  self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(600.0, 560.0);
  //[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]; 
  [self.tableView setRowHeight:60];
  [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

Got only one section:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  // Return the number of sections.
  return 1;
}
```

And all items are in the "paketListe" array:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // Return the number of rows in the section.
  return [paketListe count];
}
```

The cellForRow function only gets called, when the cell is out of view and when the cell is initially drawn.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSLog(@"CellForRow called!");
  PaketTableViewCell *cell = [[[PaketTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
  [cell setDelegate:self];
  Paket *tempPaket = [paketListe objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *userDocumentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",userDocumentsPath, [tempPaket productID], [tempPaket previewPic]];
  [cell setProductIndex:[indexPath row]];
  //... Setting some Attributes in my custom cell, cut out for simplicity....
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  return cell;
}
```

The code for the Button, this is a delegate call, so my custom sell calls [delegate buttonPushed:(int)];

```
- (void) buttonPushed:(int) myProductIndex {
  NSLog(@"Pushed: %@", [[paketListe objectAtIndex:myProductIndex] productID]);
  CoreDataWrapper *tempCDW = [[CoreDataWrapper alloc] init];
  [tempCDW initCoreData];
  Paket *tempPaket = [paketListe objectAtIndex:myProductIndex];
  //Doing some work in Core Data an my "paketListe" array. Left out for simplicity... 
  [tempCDW release];
  //Here it begins....
  [[self tableView] reloadData];
  [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
  [[self tableView] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:myProductIndex inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
```

Now I tried the reloading with different commands... Reload the whole thing with just `reloadData` or the `begin-/endUpdate` thing. Nothing refreshes the cell. After several hours of reading I think I did everything right, but no refresh.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I assume you tried `[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay]`, right?

Comment: Ah, yes, I tried this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
- (void)configureCell:(PaketTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Any cell-specific code

    [cell setNeedsLayout]; //or [cell setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Code to create any/a general cell

    [self configureCell:cell];

    return cell;
}

- (void) buttonPushed:(int) myProductIndex {

    //Code to identify the cell in which your button is (use "super")

    [self configureCell:cellForPushedButton];
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but no redraw. Configure cell gets called, everything is set fine, but no redraw. Neither with `setNeedsLayout` nor with `setNeedsDisply`. Now I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

I got to know your problem you have missed in reloadRowsAtIndexPaths "nil". 
Do as i wrote below, it will work.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:myProductIndex inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```